# Question related to future tense: "shall" vs "will"

Tags: will-shall

What is the difference between these sentences?

> Tell me, doctor, **shall** I lose weight?
>
> Tell me, doctor, **will** I lose weight?

Comment: Please write what do you think is the difference? they are two words with different meaning, what made you to think they are comparable?

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan - This question has been asked hundreds of times. Please use the "Search Q&A" box at upper right! Also, try reading [**this question**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/when-should-i-use-shall-versus-will) at ELU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between the two sentences. If you want to be pedantic you can follow the old rule:

> Well, in traditional British grammar, the rule is that will should only be used with second and third person pronouns (you; he, she, it, they). With first person pronouns (I and we), the 'correct' verb to talk about the future is shall.

<sup>([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/shall-or-will))</sup>

In everyday conversation the two modal verbs, "will" and "shall" are used interchangeably. I doubt that one in ten native English speakers would know the rule.